# WPF C# User control page IsVisibleChanged event

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

i have some user control page , and a MainWindow , so i would like to set user control page to hidden , and once its hidden , it stops its audio from playing

i know i have to do something with IsVisibleChanged event but i got stuck at how to start it?

Is it something like this ?

```
(pagename).IsVisibleChanged(object sender , RoutedEventArgs e )
 {    ap.Stop()  }
```

Because my user control page ( i display it within the mainwindow using a custom control ) is in my mainwindow and the user control page have some audio playing , when i click the home button that resides on the mainwindow , i'll set the user control page to hidden and show my home page , but now when it is hidden , the audio from that page is still playing , so i went to ask and some said use IsVisibleChanged event in user control page ( the 1 that plays the audio ) but i got stuck at how do i even write it cos i am new to this .

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First solution:

You should use `DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs` as second argument and you should check `NewValue` property that indicates if page will be visible or not ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isvisiblechanged.aspx)).

Example:

```
void (pagename)_IsVisibleChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!((bool)e.NewValue))
    {
        ap.Stop();
    }
}
```

[Here](http://sdrv.ms/19bC6I9) you find the sample solution (IsVisibleChangedExample).

Second solution:

If you use `MediaElement` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx)) to play the music, you should use two properties:
`LoadedBehavior` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.loadedbehavior.aspx)) and `UnloadedBehavior` ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.unloadedbehavior.aspx)).

Example:

```
<MediaElement Name="me" Source="path to your music file" 
              LoadedBehavior="Play" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Volume="100" />
```

Comment: Hi thanks for replying and your time . I am new to programming as well as WPF C# , kind to elaborate more? I don't really understand what you try to meant , But lets say if the user control page is in another custom control in the MainWindow , but I only set that custom control to hidden , will it detect as the user control page is hidden too or only detect that particular control that I set it to hidden . Its because I set the custom control to hidden but that user control page is inside it . Sorry for my poor English , hope u understand :)

Comment: And where should I use your code above ? in the user control page ? Thanks for clarifying my doubts and pardon me for bombarding questions , really sorry.

Comment: @user2601570 check my answer again :)

Comment: my visual studio is incompatible with the example file . However , "Play" is just play , "Stop" is just stop ? And how does it detect if its being unloaded , cos i only set it to hidden in a control.